# Python - Create dictionary of dictionaries from CSV

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, nested

I have a CSV with the first column having many duplicate values, and the second column being a predetermined code that maps to a value in the third column, such as this:

```
1, a, 24
1, b, 13
1, c, 30
1, d, 0
2, a, 1
2, b, 12
2, c, 82
2, d, 81
3, a, 04
3, b, 23
3, c, 74
3, d, 50
```

I'm trying to create a dictionary of dictionaries from a CSV, that would result in the following:

```
dict 1 = {'1':{'a':'24', 'b':'13', 'c':'30','d':'0'}, 
          '2':{'a':'1', 'b':'12', 'c':'82','d':'81'}, 
          ... }
```

My code creates the key values just fine, but the resulting value dictionaries are all empty (though some print statements have shown that they aren't during the run process)...

```
with open(file, mode='rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    dict1 = {}  # creates main dict
    for row in reader:  # iterates through the rows of the csvfile
        if row[0] in dict1:
            dict2[row[1]] = row[2]  # adds another key, value to dict2
        else:
            dict1[row[0]] = {}  # creates a new key entry for the new      dict1 key
            dict2 = {}  # creates a new dict2 to start building as the value for the new dict1 key
            dict2[row[1]] = row[2]  # adds the first key, value pair for dict2
```

Comment: You didn't assign `dict2` to be part of `dict1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for this.

```
import collections

with open(file, mode='rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    dict1 = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    for row in reader:
        dict1[row[0]][row[1]] = row[2]
```

`defaultdict` is nothing more than a dictionary which initializes values for unknown keys with a default. Here, the default is to initialize a second, new dictionary (`dict` is the dictionary constructor). Thus, you can easily set both mappings in the same line.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `dict2` and you are not setting it to be the value dict anyway. Try this modified version:

```
with open(file, mode='rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    dict1 = {}  # creates main dict
    for row in reader:  # iterates through the rows of the csvfile
        if row[0] not in dict1:
            dict1[row[0]] = {}  # creates a new key entry for the new dict1 key
        dict1[row[0]][row[1]] = row[2]  # adds another key, value to dict2
```

You can also use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to skip checking for existing keys.

Comment: One minute late. defaultdict is perfect for this.

Comment: @MichaelHoff I suggest you to undelete your answer if it works, because it demonstrated my alternative method with a code sample.